# How to use only one docker-maven-plugin configuration for Docker container and Docker host?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-maven-plugin

My Spring Boot application uses ElasticSearch, therefore I have to start an instance of ElasticSearch for integration testing. To start the [Docker container of ElasticSearch](https://www.docker.elastic.co/r/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2) I use [`docker-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin). The integration test should work on GitLab and on developer machines.

My code works on GitLab's Runner (Docker container) with a Unix socket (see [Use Docker socket binding](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding)), but not on developer machines.

The internal IP address of the Docker container (`172.17.0.2`) is not known with Docker Desktop for Windows (Docker host), see [Networking features in Docker Desktop for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/).

**Source**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.33.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <registry>docker.elastic.co</registry>          
        <imagePullPolicy>always</imagePullPolicy>
        <images>
            <image>
                <alias>elasticsearch</alias>
                <name>elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2</name>
                <run>
                    <env>
                        <discovery.type>single-node</discovery.type>
                    </env>
                    <wait>
                        <http>
                            <url>http://${docker.container.elasticsearch.ip}:9200</url>
                            <method>GET</method>
                            <status>200</status>
                        </http>
                        <time>60000</time>
                    </wait>
                </run>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>docker:start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>docker:stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Additional informations**

- The internal IP is saved in the Maven property `docker.container.elasticsearch.ip` by the `docker-maven-plugin`, see [5.2. docker:start](http://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:start).
- The network is by default `bridge`, see [5.2.5. Network](http://dmp.fabric8.io/#network-configuration).
- I can't change GitLab's runner to use Docker in Docker, see [Use Docker-in-Docker workflow with Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-workflow-with-docker-executor).
- I can't change GitLab's runner to use shell execution mode, see [Use shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-shell-executor)

**Logs**

```
[INFO] DOCKER> Pulling from elasticsearch/elasticsearch
[INFO] DOCKER> Digest: sha256:59342c577e2b7082b819654d119f42514ddf47f0699c8b54dc1f0150250ce7aa
[INFO] DOCKER> Status: Image is up to date for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
[INFO] DOCKER> Pulled elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2 in 2 seconds 
[INFO] DOCKER> [elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2] "elasticsearch": Start container 121efac6ba65
[INFO] DOCKER> [elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2] "elasticsearch": Waiting on url http://172.17.0.2:9200 with method GET for status 200.
[ERROR] DOCKER> [elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2] "elasticsearch": Timeout after 60700 ms while waiting on url http://172.17.0.2:9200
[ERROR] DOCKER> Error occurred during container startup, shutting down...
[INFO] DOCKER> [elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2] "elasticsearch": Stop and removed container 121efac6ba65 after 0 ms
[ERROR] DOCKER> I/O Error [[elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2] "elasticsearch": Timeout after 60700 ms while waiting on url http://172.17.0.2:9200]
```

**Research**

- Using port mappings and Docker host's IP address from property `docker.host.address`, doesn't work for Unix sockets, see [5.2.9. Wait](http://dmp.fabric8.io/#start-wait).
- Using `host` network doesn't work for Docker Desktop for Windows, see [Use host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

**Question**

Is it possible to use only one `docker-maven-plugin` configuration for GitLab and for developer machines?